# how to change UITableViewCell from enabled to disabled at runtime so its text goes from black to grey?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to change the enabled state of a UITableViewCell at runtime such that its appearance matches its state (black text when enabled, grey text when disabled).

When I set the cell's userInteractionEnabled property to YES/NO as the table is first loaded, I get exactly what I want: enabled cells have black text, disabled cells have grey text.

But when I navigate away from this table and then return, changing the property changes the cell's state, but not its black/grey appearance.

(I am reloading the table in 'viewWillAppear:animated:', 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' is being called, and I am changing userInteractionEnabled appropriately, as evidenced by the fact I can now select a newly enabled cell even though its text is still grey.)

This is a standard UITableViewCellStyleDefault table cell.

Any suggestions here would be most welcome.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try setting `userInteractionEnabled` in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method...

Comment: Worth a try, but no such luck. Still no change in cell's text color.

Answer (score 0):

Manually change the textColor? Would that not work?

```
cell.text.textColor = [UIColor somecolor];
```

Comment: It's a hack and shouldn't be necessary. Better to treat the cause than the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Weird iOS bug with UITableViewCell and userInteractionEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654551/weird-ios-bug-with-uitableviewcell-and-userinteractionenabled) the trick is to first set `userInteractionEnabled` and then set the text. Reversing the order does not work. I was able to verify this behavior with iOS 8.1.3. That post also has a couple of other ideas for workarounds.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I stumbled upon the same answer the next time I was looking to enable/disable table rows at runtime; now if it starts failing for me again, I'll know to check this.