# Weird iOS bug with UITableViewCell and userInteractionEnabled

Tags: ios, uitableview

I just noticed something very strange with the UITableViewCell class on iOS and the userInteractionEnabled property.

It appears that if userInteractionEnabled is set to NO *before* assigning text to the cell label, then the text is coloured grey. However, setting userInteractionEnabled to NO *after* the text has been set leaves the text colour as black (see the example code fragment below).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // swap these two lines around, and the text color does not change to grey!
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = (indexPath.row % 2) == 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";

    return cell;
}
```

This is really annoying, because it means that I end up with a different behaviour in the case that a cell is reused. The above example demonstrates this - the first page of the table shows alternate rows with grey/black text. Scroll further down so that cells get reused, and you can see that things go wrong.

I just wondered if I am doing something wrong, or if this is an iOS bug? I see the problem under iOS 5.1 on the iPad 3. Any insight really appreciated!

Comment: If you have a reproducible bug (especially with some example code) then please report it to apple: https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: I reported this to Apple (quite a while back), btw. Not heard anything yet...

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I put `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];` right before `cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` , it seems to fix the problem. This is how it is working on iOS 6.0.1

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a more convenient workaround for this problem (which I consider to be a bug):

Set the `enabled` property on `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` manually like this:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = (indexPath.row % 2) == 0;
cell.textLabel.enabled = cell.isUserInteractionEnabled;
cell.detailTextLabel.enabled = cell.isUserInteractionEnabled;
```

This led me to the answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13327632/921573